# Google Fonts Stopped Rendering

Tags: custom-masterpage, google-fonts

I have google webfonts running in my masterpage.  Everything worked fine over the weekend, but suddenly the fonts stopped rendering and now Times New Roman is showing instead.  They do not render in IE or Chrome. I have not changed the CSS;  has anyone experienced this issue with SP2013?

NEVERMIND:  Govt decided to restrict access to google fonts api.

Comment: Which version of SharePoint do you have?

Comment: it's on premise enterprise.  i was using the import method first [there were no comments before import], and then attempted to host them locally with @font-face and now have tried the link method with the google hosted link.  no go.